# Opening a file in Java on OS/X

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

The code snippet below causes this error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
> Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
> ```

```
String path = "/Users/jfaig/Documents/workspace/my_array/";
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path + "Matrix.txt"));
```

The path is valid because I can see the file listed with this code:

```
File dir = new File(path);
String[] chld = dir.list();
if(chld == null){
    System.out.println("Specified directory does not exist or is not a directory.");
    System.exit(0);
} else {
    for(int i = 0; i < chld.length; i++){
        String fileName = chld[i];
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }
}
```

I reviewed many articles about OS/X paths in Java and none solved my problem.  I'm going to try it on a Windows PC to see if the problem is particular to OS/X and/or my installation of Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

FileNotFoundException is a checked exception and needs to be handled. It has nothing to do with the file or path.

http://www.hostitwise.com/java/java_io.html

Answer (score 3):

**Its not complaining about your file** but asking you to put the handling in place if the file is not found.

If you don't want any handling done for this scenario, update your method signature with `throws FileNotFoundException` e.g for `main` method, you can write as below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundExcetion {
```

If you want to handle the exception, or wrap the above code in a `try{}catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){}` block as below:

```
try{
   File dir = new File(path);
   String[] chld = dir.list();
   if(chld == null){
   System.out.println("Specified directory does not exist or is not a directory.");
    System.exit(0);
   } else {
    for(int i = 0; i < chld.length; i++){
      String fileName = chld[i];
      System.out.println(fileName);
    }
   }   
  }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){  
    //log error
    /System.out.println("File not found");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:` means that the *real* error is listed during the output of `javac`, but it repeats it here for you. `Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException` — exceptions in Java must be explicitly caught, or re-thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Let Java do the file separators with the path and use File constructor with two arguments.

```
 File path = new File("/Users/jfaig/Documents/workspace/my_array");
 File file = new File(path, "Matrix.txt");
 System.out.println("file exists=" + file.exists()); // debug
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

And as mentioned previously you need to catch or have the method throw IOException.